# Attaches an event with another event as an item attachmentCreate

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I follow this [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/event_post_attachments#example-item-attachment) to attaches an event with another event as an item attachment, but I found if the field 'isOrganizer' is in the request body, the server will response error.

However, 'isOrganizer' is a member of [event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) collection, and I can create an event with this field successfully.

Is it a bug or any limitation of itemAttachment api?

Here are my test steps.

Step 1. POST /me/events/${event_id}/attachments

```
{   
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",   
    "name": "Holiday event22222",    
    "item": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.event",
        "subject": "Discuss gifts for children",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Let's look for funding!"
         },
         "start": {
             "dateTime": "2016-12-02T18:00:00",
             "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
          },
          "end": {
             "dateTime": "2016-12-02T19:00:00",
             "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
          },
          "isOrganizer": true,
          "organizer": {
              "emailAddress": {
                  "name": "XXX YYY",
                  "address": "xxxyyy@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }   
    } 
}
```

Step 2. The server responses 400 error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidPropertySet",
        "message": "Set action is invalid for property.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5f296510-1c47-4621-ae61-f3caff28a19d",
            "date": "2018-04-03T02:28:36"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the request body

Answer (score 0):

The `isOrganizer` is set to true if the message sender is also the organizer. It isn't a settable value, it's a calculated value.

Furthermore, in your example, you're not specifying an `organizer` value so I'm not sure how the server would even determine who `isOrganizer` would be referring too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
Is it possible that the graph api server can ignore the `isOrganizer` of request body and create item attachment successfully? (just like POST /me/events api)

Comment: Given the error, it seems not. There is no reason to set `isOrganizer`, it will be handled automatically based on the sender and organizer properties.

Comment: I still got the same error when I add `organizer` properties in the request body. Is it any wrong with my request? I update the request body in the original question.